# how to display an array elements on different page using AngularJs in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

I have this one array which stores the element value which is set to true when i view it in console i see the objects have been stored in the array but the problem is i'm unable to view it on the next page which works with same controller using using ng-repeat

My JS code to save checked item into the array

```
$scope.save = function() {
var array = [];
 for(i in $scope.checkItems) {
     console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
     if($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
         array.push(i);
     }
 }
 console.log(array);
 }
```

on the console it shows the correct array elements which i have checked in the checklist

[My Console window shows as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szwix.jpg)

My code to display elements on the next page is as follows

```
<ul>    
<li class="item itstyle" ng-repeat="items in array"
   ng-model="checkItems[items.elem]" ng-change="print()">
   {{ items.elem }}
</ul>
```

I may be doing this entirely wrong since i am a newbie to web and Ionic technologies yet any suggestion to solve this issue is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the router to pass along state then consider creating a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and store the array inside of it.

Angular will inject the service object into the controller.  Service/factory objects are singletons.

```
myApp.factory('StateService', ['http',function($http) {
  // Service injects http Service but is not used below, just an example
  // Declare variables
  var myArray = [];
  var getMyArray = function() {
      return myArray;
  }; 
 //factory method returns an object
  return {
    myArray: getMyArray

  };
}]);
```

Controller.js

```
 myApp.controller('fooController',['StateService', function(StateService) {
  $scope.theArray = StateService.myArray();
 }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lt56 could you please provide me a link for tutorial or guide so that i can look into it?

Comment: I edited the post, providing a link to documentation and an example of creating a service.

Answer (score 0):

To show values in html page from controller declare variable as

```
$scope.array = [];
```

instead of declaring with var. $scope is required to interact with HTML page. Also replace the variable array with $scope.array in for loop and console

Answer (score 0):

when you are navigating to the other page, you can pass the array to it by

```
$state.go('your-page-state', {data: myarray});
```

then you can get that value from stateParams

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

    $scope.results = $stateParams.data;

 });
```

To make this available on the View , declare it using $scope not var.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Diluk Angelo but it doesn't seems to work with my code i'm still not able to display the elements

Comment: anytime buddy :)